# What's different between generic and polymorphism in C# method's arguments?

Tags: c#, oop, generics, polymorphism

I have a class need to use a object, and the object is constraint of some kind of class.
However, I have two design for this method to implement: generic and polymorphism, then the example code like below:

```
class S3 : S{}
class S2 : S{}
class S{}

class C : A{
    public override void DoOne(S s){
        var tmp = s as S3;
    }
    public override void DoTwo<T>(T s){
        var tmp = s as S3;
    }
}
class B : A{
    public override void DoOne(S s){
        var tmp = s as S2;
    }
    public override void DoTwo<T>(T s){
        var tmp = s as S2;
    }
}
abstract class A{
    public abstract void DoOne(S s);
    public abstract void DoTwo<T>(T s) where T : S;
}

var s2 = new S2();
var b = new B();
b.DoOne(s2);
b.DoTwo(s2);
```

The class `B` need use `S2` object, and maybe I have class `C` need use `S3` object.
I don't know what's better for implement those.

Comment: There are more ways than this, why stop there? In short, both your variations are *suspect*, additionally you ***should always*** prefer composition over inheritance. However, the question lacks sufficient constraints or use-cases to make any answer useful. That's to say, this code is fine either way (it works), but you may run into several problems and limitations when you try to use any such solution in certain situation.

Comment: In fact, I want to compare performance or other consideration for those.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Neither of the two ways is type-safe. Neither prevents you from passing in an `S3` to `B` or `S2` to `C`. The usage of generics is rather redundant, when you only use `T` once as a parameter type.

A more type-safe approach would be to use a generic interface/abstract class `A`:

```
abstract class A<T> where T : S {
    public abstract void DoOne(T s);
}

class C : A<S3> {
    public override void DoOne(S3 s){
        // ...
    }
}
class B : A<S2> {
    public override void DoOne(S2 s){
        // ...
    }
}
```

This way, `C` and `B` have no common base class. This is how it should be, if you want type-safety.

If you don't want type safety (not recommended), accept an `S` instead. The generics doesn't add much here.